# reactnative pass navigate to subView

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to reactnative

I am using `FlatList` with `app.js` and using `StackNavigator` for navigation between scenes like this:

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Content',
  };


  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data = {myData}
          renderItem={({item}) => 
                            <Text style={styles.someStyle} 
                                  onPress={()=>
                                            navigate("Detail", 
                                                     {item: item});}>
                             {item.text}</Text> 
                      }
      />        
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Above code will work fine: when I pressed one of the listed item, will load another scene to show the detail of the item content.

But since I want a complex styling for the listed item, I think it will be convenient that I define the listed item in a subView like this:

```
class MyHomeListItem extends React.PureComponent {
    render(){
        return (
          <View style={styles.item}>
              <Image
                source={require('./assets/book.png')}
                style={styles.listImageIcon}
              />
              // as you can see the following `onPress` was intended for 
              // the same poperse which should load another secene to show the detail.
              <Text onPress={()=>
                              {this.props.ref("Detail", 
                                               {item: this.props.item});}} 
                    style={styles.listItemHomeText}>

                    {this.props.chapterName}: {this.props.chapterTitle}
              </Text>
          </View>
        );
    }
}
```

And I want to pass the data in the `FlatList` as a property like:

```
 <FlatList
    data = {myData}

      renderItem={({item}) => <MyHomeListItem  chapterName={item.chapterName} chapterTitle={item.chapterTitle} ref={navigate} /> }
  />
```

If I don't pass the `navigate` function to the subView, things will not work, which I think is fine so I pass it so far via `ref` which is a reference of the `navigate` function (I thought) or just via `ref={this}` and using `this.props.ref.navigate(...)` in the subView, but either wouldn't work.

It will showing:

```
_this3.props.ref is not a function....'_this3.props.ref' is undefined
```

[image]

So How can I do that?

Furthur more, I actually want the whole subView to listen to the `onPress` but I didn't find an `onPress` attribute for `<View>`

Comment: what's the prop values in subview?

Comment: ` _this3.props.ref is not a function...._this3.props.ref is undefined`

Comment: i mean can you share the full log using console.log(this.props) in render method. Place that line before return statement and share the log.

Comment: Also you are not using this.props.ref.navigate in your example code, you are using this.props.ref("Detail"...).

Comment: @AnamulHasan I am using this.props.ref() in the sample code because I pass the navigate as the ref attribute in the FlatList, I also tried using this to pass as the attribute ref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `ref` is a reserved prop for assigning the child components to be on the ref of the parent component, so that the parent component can easily reference the child component. 
Try pass it down straight through `navigation={navigate}`

Also, if you want `onPress` for the whole `View`, try wrapping the `View` in one of the `Touchable`'s, i.e. `TouchableHighlight`, `TouchableOpacity`, or `TouchableWithoutFeedback`. And pass the `onPress` function as a prop to the `Touchable` component.

Also, personally, I prefer defining the `navigation` logic in the HomePage and the `onPress` function in the item component would just pass back the corresponding object for the row back up via a `onRowPress` prop passed down from the HomeScreen component.
This way, navigation logic is not all over the place, and row item component could be generic enough that the onPress function will always just pass back the corresponding object.

Comment: Hey just tried navigation={navigate} and it worked, has edited the answer to accept it if you don't mind, thanks for the reminding that ref is a reserved word.